# Unable to ping user with small caps username on Stack Overflow Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, stack-overflow-for-teams, comment-replies

When trying to ping a user with small caps font in the Teams comments, the user is not showing up as pingable. Even when copying and pasting the name in:

[image]

This is happening for some other users also.

The ping does work for some other users:

[image]

When I go onto the users parent site and attempt to ping them under [one of their posts](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/54202/does-kicking-a-tire-off-your-car-from-underneath-it-while-its-held-up-by-a-stab/54203#54203), the ping works.

[image]

As does replying to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809777/configure-sub-sub-vertical-menu-in-css/24810109#comment38513257_24810109) on Stack Overflow.

[image]

When I use the mod superping `@@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2` in chat, the user shows up:

[image]

<sub>No superfluous pings were used during the creation of this question.</sub>

I'm using chrome on a mac.

Comment: Uh. I didn't know about the _mod superping_. May I ask what's the effect of it compared to a normal ping?

Comment: @honk no difference in effect, it means you can ping someone who has not been in that room (ever or for a while). The actual ping works the same way. The superping allows a search through all the users on the site, by name.

Comment: My ping was also on a Mac... in FF.

Comment: @honk in addition to what Yvette's said - it also allows a mod to "ping" someone even if they *don't have a chat account*.

Comment: Yeah! I'm in lights :o) Sorry for the issue with my User Name ... It was one of the reasons I put the "P" in normal case as I had changed it all to "small caps" at one time. Having the "P" as the first letter alleviated this issue most of the time (as long as someone doesn't type a normal "a" afterward.)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 wow, nice to ping you :)

Comment: I think part of the problem is not really a problem. The regular ping only works if the individual has already posted within the thread. Now that I've posted within the thread, it should pull me out without issue. However, if I had my User Name as it was before with all "small caps", it makes it *very hard* to ping in any instance.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Nope, did you see my  comment in the Team? I can't ping you under your post, or reply to you in a comment thread

Comment: Definitely screwy! Hopefully something can be done about it (other than me changing my UID! I've grown accustomed to it, lol!)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Now that we know the secret sauce, can we superping people without being a mod? :-D

Comment: @TylerH doesn't seem to work for non-mod: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42693376#42693376

Comment: I think it must be `@@<site>@<user id>`? No?

Comment: If you put three @s, it pings the user even if they don't have a stack overflow account.

Comment: If you put four @s, it pings the user even if they're not alive (dead or not yet born).

Comment: One ping to rule them all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and is up on production.